# English Translations of Hayagreeva Stotrams by Sri Vadiraja Teertha

Tags: vishnu, vaishnavism, translation-request, saint

Sri Vadiraja Teertha, considered amongst the highest saints in the Madhva hierarchy and next only to Srimad Ananda Teertha(Madhva) and Sri Jayateertha, was an unshakable devotee of SriHayavadana Perumaal(also known as Sri Hayagreeva Perumaal or Thiru Parimuga Perumaal).

[image: a pic Sri Vadiraja Teertha offering prasadam]

It is said that Sri Vadiraja Teertha used to offer daily prasadam to Perumaal Hayagreeva by holding the prasadam on his head. Hayagreeva Perumaal is said to appear in the form of a horse and eat the prasadam by kneeling on Vadirajateertha's shoulders.

Apart from the above, Sri Vadiraja Teertha famously composed many Stotrams on Hayagreeva Perumaal, some of which are the following:

- Hayavadana Astaka
- Hayagreeva Panchaka
- Hayagreeva Dhyana Prakarana
- Hayagreeva Stuthi
- Hayagreeva Sampada Stotra
- Varaha Hayavadana Stotra

My question is in two parts:

1. Is the list of Stotra on Perumaal Hayagreeva that is given above exhaustive?
2. Are there English Translations of the same available?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the list of kritis is long and these are some of the stotras of his which you have mentioned above. In one of the Madhwa [blog](https://sites.google.com/site/harshalarajesh/works-of-vadirajatirtha) there is a list of **all his kritis** based on categories.

[Hayagreeva  Sampada Stotra](http://stotrarathna.blogspot.in/2014/02/hayagreeva-sampada-stotra.html)

By
Vadhi Raja

Translated by
P.R.Ramachander

[dashAvatAra stuti](http://www.dvaita.org/haridasa/songs/vadiraja/dash_stuti.html)

[Sri Lakshmi Shobhane Introduction](http://www.dvaita.org/haridasa/songs/vadiraja/l_shoba.html)

[Avataratraya Madhva suvali Introduction (Avatara of Srimad Ananda Teertha)](http://www.dvaita.org/haridasa/songs/vadiraja/m_suvali.html)

[Vaikunta VarNane Introduction](http://www.dvaita.org/haridasa/songs/vadiraja/v_varna.html)

Comment: I think i forgot to mention explicitly in the body of the question(it's in the title nevertheless) that i'm interested exclusively in VadirajaTeertha's Stotra works on Hayagreeva. Let me add that into the body of the question now.